# Raspberry Pi + Flask + lighttpd = 'Operational Error: cannot open database file'

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

[http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux-even-on-the-raspberry-pi/page/0#][1]

And am stuck here: when I run this under lighttpd, I get this error:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError'>: (OperationalError) unable to open database file u'UPDATE user SET last_seen=? WHERE user.id = ?' ('2014-08-03 14:51:51.681210', 2) 
      args = ('(OperationalError) unable to open database file',)
```

Things I've tried:

- Running it w/ the test server (not under lighttpd) - works fine
- Applying chmod 777 to the database file (yes, yes, I know - this is
  not open to the outside world though) - still get the error Hardcode
  the database location (like below):

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + '/home/pi/microblog/app.db? check_same_thread=False'`

Nope, still get the error

I am pretty well stuck at this point.

Oh yeah, here's the relevant part of my config file for lighttpd:

```
fastcgi.server = ("/microblog" =>
    ((
        "socket" => "/tmp/microblog-fcgi.sock",
        "bin-path" => "/home/pi/microblog/runp-sqlite.fcgi",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 1
    ))
)

alias.url = (
    "/microblog/static/" => "/home/pi/microblog/app/static/",
)
```

Here's the traceback from the lighttpd log:

```
2014-08-03 11:53:09: (response.c.544) Path         : /var/www/microblog 
2014-08-03 11:53:09: (mod_fastcgi.c.3035) got proc: pid: 3419 socket: unix:/tmp/microblog-fcgi.sock-0 load: 1 
2014-08-03 11:53:37: (mod_fastcgi.c.2676) FastCGI-stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 558, in run
    protocolStatus, appStatus = self.server.handler(self)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 1118, in handler
    result = self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1666, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/home/pi/microblog/app/views.py", line 48, in before_request
    db.session.commit()
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 114, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 703, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 361, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 340, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1718, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1789, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 331, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 475, in execute
    uow
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 59, in save_obj
    mapper, table, update)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 485, in _emit_update_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1449, in execute
    params)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1584, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1698, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1691, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/pi/microblog/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 331, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
OperationalError: (OperationalError) unable to open database file u'UPDATE user SET last_seen=? WHERE user.id = ?' ('2014-08-03 15:53:37.591109', 2)

2014-08-03 11:53:40: (mod_fastcgi.c.1490) released proc: pid: 3419 socket: unix:/tmp/microblog-fcgi.sock-0 load: 0
```

and in config.py:

```
.
.
.
SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES = True
# slow database query threshold (in seconds)
DATABASE_QUERY_TIMEOUT = 0.5
WHOOSH_ENABLED=False
.
.
.
#SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db') + '?check_same_thread=False'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + '/home/pi/microblog/app.db' #?check_same_thread=False'
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')
```

Comment: Is there a traceback?

Comment: Well, there's this in the lighttpd log:

Comment: oops. I added some info to my question.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the Raspberry Pi forum of Stack Exchange. More people with RPi knowledge would see it.

Comment: In your hard coded example try it without string concatenation. You have an extra slash so it should be `sqlite:///home/...`

Comment: No, with an absolute path there should be four slashes.

Comment: I'm reverting back to the non-hardcoded path anyway now that it's all sorted. Sir Celsius thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm a big dummy.

I had not given read/write access to the parent directory of the database file.